# Spring Oauth2 Sercurity - How to implement multiple ResourceServerTokenServices

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I have a application RESTful API. Currently, my resource validated from a authorization servers. (Figure 1). I want my resource must be validated against distinct remote multiple authorization servers. (Figure 2).
[image]
How can i implement `ResourceServerTokenServices` to do this?

---

My currently setting follow `figure (1)`
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class OAuth2ClientConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerProperties sso;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ResourceServerTokenServices userInfoTokenServices() {
        CustomUserInfoTokenServices serv = new CustomUserInfoTokenServices(sso.getUserInfoUri(), sso.getClientId());
        return serv;
    }
}
```

CustomUserInfoTokenServices:

```
public class CustomUserInfoTokenServices implements ResourceServerTokenServices {

    private final String userInfoEndpointUrl;

    private final String clientId;

    public CustomUserInfoTokenServices(String userInfoEndpointUrl, String clientId) {
        this.userInfoEndpointUrl = userInfoEndpointUrl;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessToken) throws AuthenticationException, InvalidTokenException {
        // Call API from userInfoEndpointUrl
        // Extract result to get OAuth2Authentication
        return //OAuth2Authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported: read access token");
    }
```

My application properties:

```
#Resource port
server.port = 8081

# Server oauth configuare
security.oauth2.client.clientId = CLIENT_ID
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
# Authorization server
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri = http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/user/me
```